# Compare two things doesn't work

Tags: android, string, compare

I have a strange problem in my android app. I must compare two string which are equals. I tried this :

```
if (raspunsdata.equals(rok)) {
                System.out.println("changed ");

            } else
                System.out.println("no change");
        }
```

but I get always "no change". Before this I have System.out.println for both strings, and both of them have the same value.

I tried also `(raspunsdata==rok)` and `raspunsdata.contentEquals(rok)` but I have the same problem. Why? I cant understand this.,...please help...

Comment: can you display whole code from where you store this strings variables?

Comment: well...the String rok is declared in the begining of the activity like this :String rok="true";

Comment: and raspunsdata is the answer from a server : HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    /* Checking response */

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
      .getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line + NL);
    }
    in.close();
    raspunsdata = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("Raspuns data" + raspunsdata);

Comment: and what about the raspunsdata?

Comment: where you declare raspunsdata and what type it is?

Comment: raspunsdata is also String and I declare it at the begining

Comment: are there any control caharacters in any  raspundata (or possibly end CR or LF characters ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have unwanted white spaces. Might need to use the trim function just to make sure.

```
if (raspunsdata.trim.equals(rok.trim())) { 
    System.out.println("changed "); 
} else 
    System.out.println("no change"); 
}
```

Btw equals is the correct way  to check whether the values are the same.

Comment: I love you :D ...you saved me...thanks...I wouldn't have realised

Answer (score 0):

.equals - compares the values of both objects. If you have 2 Strings with the same characters sets .equals will return true;
 == - compares if two objects references are equal.
For example:

```
String a = "lol";
String b = a;
```

a == b - will be true.

Try reading: http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/qanda/pjqa00001.shtml